# Summary of models constructed for transfer learning in tensorflow keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, transfer-learning

I'm using tensorflow 2.6 keras for transfer learning. Currently I take MobileNetV2. I take input, apply some preprocessing using Lambda layer, then feed this preprocessed input to MobileNetV2, then add Dense layer and train this thing. Training, inference etc actually work as expected.

However, the summary of the model looks as follows:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           [(None, 201, 189, 1)]     0
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 201, 189, None)    0
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 201, 189, None)    0
_________________________________________________________________
mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Functi (None, 7, 6, 1280)        2257984
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 53760)             0
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 2)                 107522
=================================================================
Total params: 2,365,506
Trainable params: 2,331,394
Non-trainable params: 34,112
```

So the MobileNetV2 structure is hidden and shown as one layer of type `tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional`. If I print summary of this layer, I get all the internal layers of the model. I have a script for automatic GradCam visualizations which looks for the last Conv layer of the model. If the model is constructed by hand using Lambda, Conv2D, Dense layers, then everyhting works fine. If I use pretrained model, then currently it fails, because the Conv layer is hidden inside of this Functional layer.

How do I construct my modified MobileNetV2 model with my additional layers so that the full structure of the model is shown?

This is how I approximately construct my final model:

```py
input = Input(shape=params.image_shape, name="input")
flow = input
flow = input_correction(flow, params) #some Lambda layers
keras_model = MobileNetV2(
            input_shape=image_shape,
            weights='imagenet',
            include_top=False)
keras_model_output=keras_model(flow)
keras_model_input=input
keras_model_output = Flatten()(keras_model_output)
output = Dense(units=len(params.classes),
                   activation=tf.nn.softmax,
                   name="output")(keras_model_output)
model = Model(inputs=keras_model_input, outputs=output)
model.compile(...)
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Comment: I want a model with all the layers visible and not hidden inside one large mobilenetv2_1.00_224 tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional.

Answer (score 1):

In default, summary doesnt show nested models. Just include `expand_nested` argument in the summary.

```
model.summary(expand_nested=True)
```

Comment: This only works for TF 2.7 or higher but not 2.6.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I think I've found the right term for what I want. I want to unnest the nested MobileNet2 model e.g. to be able to produce GradCam
Probably something like that but I have to try it https://groups.google.com/g/keras-users/c/lJcVK25YDuc/m/atB6TfwqBAAJ?pli=1